# NativeScript-Vue Firebase + FireStore use

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nativescript

Im trying to use FireStore for my NativeScript-Vue android app. FireBase initialization is succesfull. Now I want to access to my collection which has one document. In my .Vue component  tags i write this:

```
import {firestore} from "@nativescript/firebase"

mounted() {
//fetch data from the firestore
firestore.collection('Husqvarnas').get()
.then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id)
  })
})}
```

What im trying to do there is to console.log all the data, and Documents individually with 'doc.id'
But i get **nothing**. No errors, no results. If I add bellow console.log this code:

```
let husky = doc.data();
    husky.id = doc.id;
    this.Husqvarnas.push(husky)
```

and trying to display it with this code:

```
<ListView for="husky in Husqvarnas" :key="husky.id"> <!-- :key="husky.Model" -->
    <v-template>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label :text="`Model: ${husky.Model}`" textWrap="true"/>
            <Label :text="`Front Compression: ${husky.FCompr}`" textWrap="true"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

I get "**Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**".
Here i am
Initializing firebase:

```
var firebase = require("@nativescript/firebase").firebase;
firebase.init({
}).then(
    function () {
        console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);
```

And getting "firebase.init done", so its working.

What i am doing **WRONG?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one:

```
mounted() {
    firestore.collection("Husqvarnas").get()
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Same 'id of undefined'. When <ListView for="husky in Husqvarnas" :key="husky.id">
I delete :key="husky.id"
Then i  get no error, but no console.log as well

Comment: Can you also include your Firestore data in ypur question

Comment: For what reasons ?

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt submit my question answer, because it was of the security rules, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It was Security Rules, had to change in default rules from False, to True.

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```